# Using SVG feTurbulence as a filter causes odd rendering issues in Safari

Tags: css, svg, safari

I have been toying around with clouds in css using SVGs and fractal noise but the rendered output is full of glitches in Safari 13 (latest at time of test). An example of this can be seen at the following code pen:

https://codepen.io/beauhaus/pen/315327cfbb84e1fca1057d851dec8fde

```
<svg width="0" height="0"> 
    <filter id="filter">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency=".01" numOctaves="10" />
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="180" />
    </filter>
</svg>
```

If you resize the preview UI in Safari you will see the clouds have odd render lines between them.

Comment: You should report bugs to the [webkit bugtracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert is right, you should [report this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/).

However, there seems to be a simple workaround:

Forcing your filtered element to have it's own layer apparently makes the bug disappear: (only tested with `transform`, maybe my explanation is off).

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  background: linear-gradient(165deg, #527785 0%, #7FB4C7 100%);
  padding: 1%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#cloud-circle {
    width: 500px;
    height: 275px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    filter: url(#filter);
    box-shadow: 400px 400px 60px 0px #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: -320px;
    left: -320px;
    /* Safari workaround */
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="cloud-circle"></div>
  <svg width="0" height="0"> 
    <filter id="filter">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency=".01" numOctaves="10" />
      <feDisplacementMap in="SourceGraphic" scale="180" />
    </filter>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah I get you and yes that works - thanks so much. I'll get on with reporting it (if it has not been already)